# mysql regex - filter for a number greater than XX when followed by a specific string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, regular-language

Im searching for a RegEx that I can use in my MySql Query

What I want to archive is a query that filters all rows where there is a string with the the value "xx% to Fire Resistance" while xx is a dynamic value , lets say 22 , but I dont just want all rows with 22 but all rows with 22 AND **higher**. Is that somehow possible ?

I could filter it in a second step with php, but the initial result would be way to big to be practical to work with.

What I currently have (and does not rly work because it just filters for a number before the given string)

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE `mods` REGEXP '\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)% to Fire Resistance\b'
```

What I would need in theory

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE `mods` REGEXP '\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)% to Fire Resistance\b' > 22
```

one example "mods" field content

```
Some more text;+170 to Accuracy Rating;+25% to Fire Resistance;+4 to Armour;+6 to Evasion Rating;+43 to maximum Life;+39% to Lightning Resistance;Some more text;Some more text;
```

https://regex101.com/r/ZhIMzc/2

Comment: If you want to use the regex in MySQL, you can only use `\b` in v.8+. What is your MySQL version?

Comment: What is the range of valid values for fire resistance?

Comment: @ Wiktor mysqld  Ver 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu)) should be the Version I use, but it would be possible to update if neccessary.

@ danblack the range would be smth like 1-99%

Comment: Try `REGEXP '[[:<:]](2[2-9]|[3-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{2,})([.][0-9]+)?% to Fire Resistance[[:>:]]'` in an older MySQL version. The `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` are `\b`s, and non-capturing groups should be turned into capturing ones.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you Sir endet my 5hour misery, thats exactly what I needed, it works like a charm and I'm even kinda understand what it does :D thank you

Comment: SQL is not designed for dissecting a string; you might find a way for this specific problem, but there is no general solution.

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL versions before 8, you may use

```
REGEXP '[[:<:]](2[2-9]|[3-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{2,})([.][0-9]+)?% to Fire Resistance[[:>:]]'
```

**Details**

- `[[:<:]]` - left-hand word boundary
- `(2[2-9]|[3-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{2,})` - a group matching

  - `2[2-9]` - `2` followed with a digit from `2` to `9`
  - `|` - or
  - `[3-9][0-9]` - a digit from `3` to `9` and then any 1 digit
  - `|` - or
  - `[1-9][0-9]{2,}` - a digit from `1` to `9` and then two or more digits
- `([.][0-9]+)?` - an optional `.` and 1+ digits
- `% to Fire Resistance` - a substring
- `[[:>:]]` - right-hand word boundary